# Can weapon/armor effects be switched between items freely?

Tags: path-of-exile

If I buy a weapon/armor effect and I place it into an item...

Will I be able to remove it from the item and place it into another, or it gets locked once I apply it for the first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can freely remove a weapon/item effect from one item/character and move it to another.

Press the 'M' key to open the microtransactions window and click on Reclaim effect button.

The only effect that this does not fully apply to is "Skin Transfer" - in which reclaiming it returns the item whose skin was transfered, but not the skin transfer microtransaction itself.